# How to explicitly unsubscribe from a collection?

Tags: meteor

I have a MongoDB with a large "messages" collection; all messages belonging to a specific `groupId`. So have started with a publication like this:

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function(groupId) {
  return Messages.find({
    groupId: groupId
  });
});
```

and a subscription like this:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
   return Meteor.subscribe("messages", Session.get("currentGroupId"));
});
```

This got me into trouble because initially `currentGroupId` is undefined but sill mongod would use up the CPU to find messages with `groupId == null` (although I know there are none).

Now, I tried to rewrite the publication as follows:

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function(groupId) {
  if (groupId) {
    return Messages.find({
      groupId: groupId
    });
  } else {
    return {}; // is this the way to return an empty publication!?
  }
});
```

and/or to rewrite the subscription to:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
   if (Session.get("currentGroupId")) {
     return Meteor.subscribe("messages", Session.get("currentGroupId"));
   } else {
     // can I put a Meteor.unsubscribe("messages") here!?
   }
});
```

which both helps initially. But as soon as `currentGroupId` becomes undefined again (because the user navigates to a different page), mongod is still busy requerying the database for the last subscribed `groupId`. So how can I unsubscribe from a publication such that the mongod is stopped being queried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply adding a condition to the publication:

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function(groupId) {
  if (groupId) {
    return Messages.find({
      groupId: groupId
    });
});
```

and keeping the subscription:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
  return Meteor.subscribe("messages", Session.get("currentGroupId"));
});
```

does the job.

There is no need to stop the publication explicitly. Eventually, the MongoDB is not queried anymore after finishing the currently running query and issuing yet another one (which seems to be queued somewhere in the system).

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any documentation to prove this claim. A hint would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

According to the documentation it must be http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_stop

> this.stop()
>   Call inside the publish function. Stops this client's subscription;
>   the onError callback is not invoked on the client.

So something like

```
Meteor.publish("messages", function(groupId) {
  if (groupId) {
    return Messages.find({
      groupId: groupId
    });
  } else {
    return this.stop();
  }
});
```

And I guess on the client side you can just remove your if/else like in your first example

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
   return Meteor.subscribe("messages", Session.get("currentGroupId"));
});
```

Comment: I guess you have a type here. `Messages` does not have a `stop` method. I guess it should say `return this.stop();` instead.

Comment: I believe you are right, according to the doc the call stop() is a method of Meteor.publish, so I changed it to this.stop().

Comment: Now, the funny thing is that omitting the call to stop()  does not change the behavior. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I found it more simple and straight-forward to call the `.stop()` function on the handler which is returned from the `.subscribe()` call:

```
let handler = Meteor.subscribe('items');
...
handler.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case, you should stop the `autorun`

there is an example in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_autorun)

Your autorun is actually called with a parameter that allows you to stop it:

```
Deps.autorun(function (c) {
  if (! Session.equals("shouldAlert", true))
    return;

  c.stop();
  alert("Oh no!");
});
```

Comment: Stopping the `autorun` won't help because I need to load (i.e. subscribe to) messages again once `currentGroupId` is not null anymore.